# http error when uploading media files

Tags: uploads, errors, media, http

I am having this same annoying issue many other have: When I am trying to upload images into Wordpress via the media uploader, it gives me an **http error**. Now I have tried the following, but nothing works:

- Multi-File uploader and the Simple browsers uploader
- Everything as stated in this [post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/59763/how-to-fix-http-error-when-uploading-images), including the 'memory fix', but still not.

What is even more strange, and pointing to a server problem perhaps, is the following:

- I have a shared Linux hosting server account
- Inside the public_html folder, I have 4 different wordpress websites, where each website uses its own wordpress installation, **and they all have the same problem**
- I use different versions of wordpress - 3.5 and 3.6 between the different installations
- Even starnger, is that up until today, everything worked great, until I added another folder for a new wordpress installation.
- Each installation uses its own DB
- I do not use multi-site

Can anyone please tell me why I keep getting this error?

Thanks!

Comment: Which PHP version are you using? I have seen this with PHP 5.3 only.

Comment: Hey. sorry for the late reply. The version I am using is: PHP version 5.3.27

Comment: What do you suggest I do?

Comment: PHP 5.3 is a out of date already, try an upgrade.

Comment: Thank you Toscho. I have contacted my Web Host Provider and I will update here as soon as the upgrade is done.