# What is the source of "HTTP error," and

Tags: errors

I occasionally receive an error in the WordPress backend:  ["HTTP error."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/My9Yn.jpg)  I'd like to troubleshoot myself, but first I want to know the source of the message.  Is this a message generated by WordPress?  Or has some other software (e.g. a plugin, my server OS, etc) generated the message?  Either way, is there any *official documentation* regarding this error message?   All I can find online is third party information on possible causes of the message--I can't find anything official.

There are many existing questions about "HTTP error" on this site:

- [question 1](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/112457/http-error-when-uploading-media-files)
- [question 2](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7111/wordpress-upload-http-error)
- [question 3](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/166806/http-error-when-trying-to-upload-image)

but I have not found any that ask/answer my specific question.

To be clear, I'm not looking for tips on how to resolve the error.  I would like to learn more about the error message, and as an initial step, I'd like to hunt down the official documentation on the error, if any.  If I still need more assistance after, then I will consult one of the third party guides I have already found (many on this very site).

Comment: I have never seen that error message in 10 years of working with WordPress. Must be a plugin/theme - have you tried searching for "HTTP Error" across all your plugin & theme files?

Comment: I have not tried that search.  It sounds like a decent first step.  How would I approach it though?  Would I need SSH access?  Or might I be able to do it from the WordPress GUI?

Comment: Your browser is reporting the HTTP error.  Very unlikely that a plugin is creating this output.  It is very possibly a problem with a plugin causing the problem but the browser is the likely source of the actual message.  Check the logs.

Comment: @jdm2112 Checking logs is a good idea.  But which logs?  wp_debug_log?  Or a browser log (Chrome, in this case)?

Comment: PHP error log would be the first place I would check.

Comment: @jdm2112 thanks I'll try that.  It may take a few days (weeks even) before I have another opportunity to do so.