# "HTTP Error" or Network Error (tcp_error) when uploading image

Tags: images, uploads, errors

I am using WordPress 4.9.4 with Astra Themes.

When I login to the dashboard and try uploading an image I get a red box with a message "HTTP Error" or Network Error (tcp_error).

I have tried add define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64MB'); on wp-config.php, change permission on wp-content/uploads/ to 775 but the message still exist.

What should i do to solve this problems?

thank you

Comment: pls check - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/59763/how-to-fix-http-error-when-uploading-images?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

step 1 : Log into your cPanel dashboard.

step 2 : Using the file manager, navigate to your WordPress site's root directory.

step 3 : Locate and open the .htaccess file for editing.

step 4 Add the following line of code at the top of the file:

```
SetEnv MAGICK_THREAD_LIMIT 1
```

step 5 Save the changes to the .htaccess file.