# WordPress “Link has expired” error on updating posts

Tags: php, errors, authentication, nonce

I'm maintaining a WordPress site on GoDaddy for a client and they started to get the "this link has expired error" when they saved a post. It does not happen when I upload a file. However, I am getting an "http error" error when I try and upload a file.

I've done some research, everyone who experiences this error seems to find a solution with updating the php config files to allow larger uploads, longer input times and so forth. This did not seem to work. I've included the phpinfo information below just incase.

From what I've gathered it seems to be an issue with the Nonces, but the clients did not update any plugin or update wordpress. Nothing should have changed, and I don't have enough experience to understand what's happening here.

Here is what I have done:

- Disabled plugins
- Changed themes
- Updated php config to reflect changes below
- Updated php to 7.2

[image: php info page screenshot]
[image: php info page screenshot]
[image: php info page screenshot]

Any ideas?

EDIT:
When I update the Authentication Keys and Salts (from [here](https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/)), it works once and then stops working.

EDIT2:
I discovered the theme is the culprit (Jupiter 6). However, once de-activated, the situation still happens until my cookies are cleared and I log out and back in. Updating and installing the theme again does not seem to have solved the problem. On a fresh install of wordpress, the theme works fine.

Comment: Server issue, I guess. Perhaps GoDaddy can help you.. Or check the `.htaccess` file and custom `php.ini` file, if any. See also [Debugging in WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress).

Comment: What am I looking for in either of these?

Comment: Anything (errors, warnings, notices, etc.) that could help you identify the (source of the) problem.. because you can change PHP settings from the `.htaccess` and a custom `ini.php` file, and for example, with `WP_DEBUG_LOG` enabled, you could check WordPress-specific errors in `wp-content/debug.log`. And I mentioned those files because they're not in the list of what you've tried, as posted in your question.

Comment: I meant `php.ini`... But anyway, I'm not an expert and just trying to give you some ideas which I hope would bring you to the solution of the issue. Cheers!

Comment: Sounds like the ImageMagick bug... This may help: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/59763/how-to-fix-http-error-when-uploading-images

Comment: Thanks @SallyCJ. No luck on the .htaccess or the debug log. Neither mentioned anything besides to be discontinued functions.

Comment: @Jersh, the other option I didn't mention is backup everything and re-install WordPress.. though I'm not positive that would help. Secondly, what is the exact error message? Is it exactly "This link has expired."? And you're probably correct that it's a nonce issue - the error could be coming from [`wp_nonce_ays()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nonce_ays/) which is used by the [`check_admin_referer()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/check_admin_referer/) function and which is used on WordPress admin pages such as `wp-admin/post.php`.

Comment: And if you could solve that one, the "http error" might very well be solved as well. Could it be a caching issue - perhaps via a file somewhere in `wp-content/mu-plugins`? (if the folder exists) Check also the `wp-config.php` file also in case it has anything related to caching. Another option you could try *first* is, in the `wp-config.php` file, replace all the "Authentication Unique Keys and Salts" - you can generate them [here](https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/) - but of course, all users would need to re-login.

Comment: @SallyCJ It worked once! I updated the authentication keys and salts in `wp-admin.php`. Then it stopped working. Any ideas? EDITED: It only worked once :(

Comment: Wow, that's strange.. but could you please try again updating the authentication keys and salts, and confirm that it works only once? And what's the exact error message?

Comment: Apologies for the delay @SallyCJ. In my experimentation to explain this phenomenon, I discovered the theme is the culprit (Jupiter 6). However, once de-activated, the situation still happens until my cookies are cleared and I log out and back in. I contacted my theme's support and they advised me to update the theme. I got my hands on the theme update which took some time, and it does not seem to have solved the problem. On a fresh install of wordpress, the theme works fine. Any ideas?

Comment: By "fresh install", you mean with all the default WordPress data (posts, themes, plugins, etc.)? And I'm not sure what's wrong, but try these as a workaround: 1) Back-up/export your database; 2) Import the database from the WordPress site with the fresh install (*everything is default*); 3) Install all the active plugins from the problematic site (and I mean, don't copy the plugin files - install them manually). Then check if the issue persists. (All these steps take time, but worth trying)

Comment: I'm so confused. My client ended up clearing caches and clearing cookies and the site works for them now. However, it still does not work for me. I've obliterated my entire history and it still doesn't work. I'm not sure what happened, but it's temporarily resolved as I don't need access. Thanks so much for you help @SallyCJ

Comment: Well, you could try private browsing - e.g. the incognito mode in Chrome. But anyway, I'm glad to hear the site is now working for the client. It's just that, it might be helpful to consult the GoDaddy's tech support - who knows, they might be able to tell what happened and then solve whatever the real problem is.

Comment: See, I did all my testing in private browsing mode for this very reason. Godaddy could not figure out the issue either.

Comment: Ah, okay. :) And I was actually also going to say, try a different computer, smartphone, tablet, etc., and even try using someone else's Internet connection? :D I mean, it's possible that there's something (like a setting, maybe) in your computer/device which is making the site (and just that site) to not work for you...

Answer (score 0):

I am also under same issues, it not only happen when you update a posts but also when you try to update your profile.

Temporary fix:

1. Log out of the wordpress panel.
2. Clear or remove all the cookie.
3. Log back in, remember to check remember me.

This seems to solve the issue but as the cookie of remember me will expire which is after 15 days of your log in date. You again have to do all the above steps.

I guess there is something with the Godaddy hosting, not our plugins, themes or browser.

Are you facing issues with classic editor, it default open text tab and the icons are white.