# How To Reset Ownership And Permissions of Wp-Content Folder, In Order to Fix HTTP Error When Uploading Images to WordPress Media Library

Tags: wp-admin, errors, media-library, permissions, http

I've noticed several articles about how to deal with the HTTP error when uploading images to the WP Media library:

[How to Fix HTTP Error When Uploading Images?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/59763/how-to-fix-http-error-when-uploading-images)

However, I've already tried adding this code to the `functions.php` file:

```
add_filter( 'wp_image_editors', 'change_graphic_lib' );

function change_graphic_lib($array) {
    return array( 'WP_Image_Editor_GD', 'WP_Image_Editor_Imagick' );
}
```

(As was suggested by the most upvoted answer in that article)

And I've also tried some of the things that were suggested in the accepted answer of that article, such as adding `define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256MB');` to the `wp-config.php` file, and adding the following codes to the `.htaccess` file:

1. `AddType x-mapp-php5 .php`
2. `<IfModule mod_security.c>
   SecFilterEngine Off
   SecFilterScanPOST Off
   </IfModule>`
3. `# Exclude the file upload and WP CRON scripts from authentication
   <FilesMatch "(async-upload\.php|wp-cron\.php|xmlrpc\.php)$">
   Satisfy Any
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
   Deny from none
   </FilesMatch>`

But still the HTTP error remains.

I admit - I haven't yet tried the suggestions in [this article](https://hookagency.com/25-image-media-uploader-problems-wordpress) (25 Image Media Uploader Problems – WordPress), but before I do, I also heard that I should try **resetting the ownership and permissions of the wp-content folder**. And I would like to try that first.

So, what does it mean to reset the ownership and permissions of this folder? Would I simply need to follow the instructions in [this article](https://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-fix-file-and-folder-permissions-error-in-wordpress/) (How to Fix File and Folder Permissions Error in WordPress)?

The article suggests changing the folder permissions to 755 (my folders already have this permission)

[image]

And the file permissions to 644.

[image]

But I'm nervous about doing this. I don't want to make any changes that can't be undone and I'm not even sure if this is what's meant by resetting ownership and permissions of the `wp-content` folder.

Please advise as to whether or not this is the best way of "resetting the ownership and permissions of the wp-content folder", and if you think it will help to eliminate the HTTP error when uploading images to the WordPress media library.

Thanks.

**EDIT:** Screenshots of HTTP error:

[image]

[image]

**EDIT 2**: I have noticed that images with smaller file sizes are able to upload without error. I.e. an image of 578 KB will upload but an image of 610 KB or above will not.

**EDIT 3**: Setting the permissions of the folders in the root directory to `755` and the permissions of the files in the root folder to `644` as is suggested in the article [How to Fix File and Folder Permissions Error in WordPress](https://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-fix-file-and-folder-permissions-error-in-wordpress/) **did not work**. The HTTP error when uploading files remains:

[image]

I also tried calling my hosting company, and they upgraded PHP to version 7.1 for this website, but the error still remains.

Comment: What error do you get? Check file permissions for wp-content/uploads (and subdirectories), not just the root level files. Setting them to 755 (dirs) and 644 (files) won't break anything, you can safely do that. Just make sure to check the "recurse into subdirectories" checkbox

Comment: I added screenshots of the HTTP error. I have started the first step - setting the directories to 755 with "recurse into subdirectories" checked. And I will set the files to 644 once this is complete. Changing the permissions currently looks like this in FTP: https://i.imgur.com/MTWH72B.png

Comment: This error just appeared, right? You could upload images before? I would probably contact the host, it might either be a change in PHP config or something such as no available space left

Comment: That is correct - it wasn't happening earlier. Sure - will contact them.

Comment: Just for the record, the hosting company upgraded PHP to version 7.1 for this website (that was their only idea), but the error still remains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try increasing WordPress Memory Limit to 256M
The most common cause of this error is lack of memory available for WordPress to use. To fix this, you need to increase the amount of memory PHP can use on your server.

You can do this by adding the following code to your **wp-config.php** file.

```
define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' );
```

This code increases the WordPress memory limit to 256MB, which would be enough to fix any memory limit issues.

If you still face the same issue then try this code. paste this code in the functions.php  file of your active theme.

```
function wp_image_uploading( $editors ) {
    $gd_editor = 'WP_Image_Editor_GD';
    $editors = array_diff( $editors, array( $gd_editor ) );
    array_unshift( $editors, $gd_editor );
    return $editors;
}
add_filter( 'wp_image_editors', 'wp_image_uploading' );
```

Also, Try adding this code in your .htaccess file.

```
SetEnv MAGICK_THREAD_LIMIT 1
```

Verify your file and folder permissions.

Comment: Wow, it was your second suggestion, specifically the line `add_filter( 'wp_image_editors', 'wp_image_uploading' );` that fixed the problem. 

What I had before was `add_filter( 'wp_image_editors', 'wpb_image_editor_default_to_gd' );`

And changing that to `add_filter( 'wp_image_editors', 'wp_image_uploading' );` is allowing me to upload images to the media library again. The rest of my code was the same as in your answer. 

I'm not sure what it is about `'wpb_image_editor_default_to_gd' );`, specifically, that fixed the problem. Do you know? Thanks!